# How to handle an error occuring before the async call in promise pattern?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling, promise, angular-promise

Classical promise pattern could be (using Angular's $q syntax) :

```
function myFunction() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    myAsyncCall(
        function(result) {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        },
        function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
}

myFunction().then(
    function(result) {
        console.log("Yeah, everything OK ! " + result);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("Booh, an error occured ! " + error);
    }
);
```

What is (are ?) the best practice(s) to handle a case where a condition result in a error before the call of the async function ?

Example:

```
function myFunction(CONDITION) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (! CONDITION) {
        /***********************
         * What to do here ???
         ***********************/
    } else {
        myAsyncCall(
            function(result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            },
            function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            }
        );
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}

myFunction(CONDITION).then(
    function(result) {
        console.log("Yeah, everything OK ! " + result);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("Booh, an error occured ! " + error);
    }
);
```

I see 2 solutions, but none of its are really sexy :

- return null instead of the promise, but it complexify the use of the function the promise should simplify ...
- call a timeout of 0.5s where I call a `deferred.reject("condition-is-false")` instead of proceeding to the async call when the condition is rejected

What do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `reject` directly, there is no problem with doing that. By far, it's the best pattern. E.g:

```
function myFunction(CONDITION) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (!CONDITION) {
      reject('The error message, or something like that');
    }
    else {
      myAsyncCall(function(result) {
        resolve(result);
      },
      function(error) {
        reject(error);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I've created a snippet with the `Q` library, so you can see that it works smoothly:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var div = document.querySelector('div');
  
  function myFunction(CONDITION) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    if (!CONDITION) {
      deferred.reject('there was an error');
    } else {
      myAsyncCall(
        function(result) {
          deferred.resolve(result);
        },
        function(error) {
          deferred.reject(error);
        }
      );
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  myFunction(false).then(function(res) {
    div.innerHTML = res;
  }).catch(function(err) {
    div.innerHTML = err;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kriskowal/q/v1/q.js"></script>
<div></div>
```